# The usage of conditional with the pairs “neither/nor” and “either /or”

Tags: conditional-constructions

1. If I could neither eat nor drink, then I would certainly get sick soon.
2. If I did neither eat nor drink, then I would certainly get sick soon.
3. If I couldn’t either eat or drink, then I would certainly get sick soon.

I would like to know whether the above sentences are grammatically correct and what is the difference of their meaning.

Comment: "did neither eat nor drink" is probably technically correct, but it is very uncommonly used that way. Something like "If I neither ate nor drank" would be more common.

Comment: @ Abby T. Miller, whenever, as a non native, I try not to make mistakes, or at least as few as posiible, I "technically" simply use "did”.  Now I know how to use them. Thank you for the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first and the third one are identical in meaning:

If you would not be able to eat or drink, you would get sick soon.

The second one means something different: if you do not eat or drink might imply you might be able to, but for some reason you *do* not.

The difference between the first and the third sentence is that I prefer the first one.
The "couldn't either/or" seems a bit more complex than the "could neither/nor".
That said, both are correct, and I will not argue over tasts :)